# Xamarin.Forms TableView EntryCell not displaying correctly on UWP

Tags: xamarin.forms

I have a very simple Xamarin.Forms App, consisting only of a TableView with Content.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TableTest"
         x:Class="TableTest.MainPage">
    <TableView>
        <TableRoot>
            <TableSection Title="Foo">
                <EntryCell Label="Cell1"
                           x:Name="TestCell"/>
                <EntryCell Label="Cell2"
                           x:Name="TestCell2"/>
            </TableSection>
    </TableRoot>
</TableView>
```

I now set the Text for the Cells by overriding the OnAppearing() method.

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
{
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        base.OnAppearing();
        TestCell.Text = "Zazzle";
        TestCell2.Text = "Brrzzz";
    }
}
```

This works fine on Android, but using UWP the first Cell appears collapsed and only returns to the expected state after moving the mouse on the cell. 
[This is a screenshot of the undesirable result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pecv8.png) What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
<StackLayout>  
    <Label Text="Entry Cell Demo for Android and UWP (Xamarin.Forms)" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />  
    <TableView Intent="Form">  
        <TableRoot>  
            <TableSection Title="My Form">  
                <EntryCell Label="Name:" HorizontalTextAlignment="Start" LabelColor="Black" Placeholder="Enter Name Here" />  
                <EntryCell Label="City :" LabelColor="Black" Placeholder="Enter City Here" /> </TableSection>  
        </TableRoot>  
    </TableView>  
</StackLayout>
```

Reference : [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/entry-cell-in-xamarin-forms-application-for-android-and-uwp/)

Comment: The Stacklayout is the part I was missing, now it does work as expected.

Comment: @evasivepi enjoy coding.